# How can I exclude test classes when running nativeTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-native

I have a Spring boot 3.1.4 application that has some tests that use things like `@DataJpaTest`/`@WebMvcTest`/etc that use mocking & whatnot which aren't supported when running in native test mode.

Is there a way I can exclude these tests from running when running the `nativeTest` maven profile?

I do want them to run in JVM mode though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark test with via the @EnabledInNativeImage and @DisabledInNativeImage annotations.

Example to not run a test when running nativeTest profile:

```
@Test
@DisabledInNativeImage
void neverWithinNativeImage() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you! Interesting that I couldn't find it anywhere in the Spring documentation, although these annotations do come directly from JUnit. Would have been nice though for the Spring docs to mention it.